# how to setenv from specman?

Tags: python, specman, setenv

I want to set specman environment variables in order to call a python from e in Xcelium.
When I setenv variables in the simulation directory - Xcelium doesn't recognize them.
How to setenv from the console or using Tcl or any other solution?

I setenv environment variables in simulation directory, but got error message in xcelium that they are not set

Answer (score 0):

can you be more specific - what variable do you try to set, and is not recognized? are these variables that are used in the e code?

Comment: I am trying to set environment variables for python running from e code. e.g. :  setenv SPECMAN_PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR `xmroot`/tools/python/64bit/include/python3.6m

Answer (score 0):

the setenv seems correct (assuming this is the right path). and should be set from the terminal (not from Specman, from Linux. from the simulation directory)

have you set the other variables?

setenv SPECMAN_PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR /pkgs/python/v3.7.2/include/python3.7m

setenv SPECMAN_PYTHON_LIB_DIR /pkgs/python/v3.7.2/lib

setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:${SPECMAN_PYTHON_LIB_DIR}

setenv PYTHONPATH ./